# Training the learning model on the log transformed data?

Tags: regression, distributions, data-transformation, model, logarithm

So I've gone through this [CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers), and in my primitive understanding I assume we do log transformation when we 'care' about relative changes and also to even out the positive skweness from our data.
So for example let's imagine having a dataset as follows:

```
Quantity  Area  TotalSF  Year  Price
    7     1710   856     2003  321510
    6     1262   1262    1976  183190
    7     1786   920     2001  228410
    7     1717   756     1915  171230
    8     2198   1145    2000  201000
```

After log transforming 'Area', 'Price' and 'TotalSF' the respective plots shows nice normal distribution.
The log transformed data looks something like this:

```
 Quantity  Area     TotalSF     Year  Price
    7    7.444249   6.752270    2003  18.34
    6    7.140453   7.140453    1976  17.75
    7    7.487734   6.824374    2001  17.92
    7    7.448334   6.628041    1915  17.43
    8    7.695303   7.043160    2000  18.12
```

My **questions** are:

- Are we going to train our model on this log transformed data ?
- If yes, then do we need to log transform our test data as well ?
- How do we get back the normal/actual values, say for the variable 'Price', after log transforming it ?

*Edit*:
This question specifically asks for suggestions whether to train a model based on log transformed data or not, and **how** to get the actual values back - more of a beginner-friendly question. The [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115571/back-transforming-regression-results-when-modeling-logy) that's used to flag this question as a duplicate on the other hand asks whether **it is valid to back transform** or not.
That's a completely different premise, I believe.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the data? Train a linear regression model?

Comment: @Stergios , yes. That would be a use case

Comment: @Nuhman: Thanks, will have a look. Can you please post a link for (some) data so I can make some examples?

Comment: What, in practical terms, do you want to optimize while performing this regression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can train your model on the log-transformed data
2. If you do (1) then you necessarily need to log-transform your test data as well
3. You can get the initial 'price' value by using `exp()` since `exp(ln(x)) = x`